# Controllable rising edge shifting circuit using CMOS

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, cmos, delay, cascode

I am building a circuit using CMOS transistors (350n technology) in which I have to delay the rising edge of a pulse, but not the falling edge. The circuit I made is the following :

[image: Circuit]

And here is the result I obtain:

[image: Plot]

I have to make the delay controllable by adding an analog input and this delay has to be as linearly dependent on the analog input as possible.

My first idea was to add an NMOS transistor between transistors M3 and M8 and so control the speed of discharge of the capacitor, but this does not make the control linearly dependent.

What is the best way to do this and how can I improve my circuit (to make Vout sharper for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your circuit works as expected for the parts used but is a non-linear function of the voltage-controlled current mirror R and load C to yield approx. T=RC/2

They can all be identical FETs using 4xxx series or 74HC series or 74ALC series which essentially changes the RdsOn vs Vdd and Ciss so the rise times are slowest with what you are using similar to 4xxx series.

A more sensitive control changes R1 towards RdsOn but Vc is still inversely related to delay due to the inverse quadratic function of RdsOn vs Vgs.

A faster rise time is only possible by reducing Ciss*RdsOn or slightly with another buffer which amplifies the intermediate slew rate.

To make this linear , you need a linear VCCC sink instead of this one ( e.g. NPN CE or Howland)

To make it more sensitive reduce R1 to 1K and increase C for lower T~RC/2 and

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you some ideas (since this sounds like homework):

To make the delay linearly controllable, you could build a voltage-controlled current source and inject its current into the drain of M7 (instead of generating the current via resistor R1). You might need some more current mirrors for that.

And to make the output edge steeper, you could build a Schmitt trigger.